# Show that angular momentum is independent of the angle

Tags: classical-mechanics, atomic-physics, orbital-motion, semiclassical

I was thinking about the Bohr atomic model which states, that the angular momentum (L) must be an integral multiple of the reduced Planck constant, this implies that $L=mvr$ must be constant for a given orbit:

$$mvr=n\frac{h}{2\pi}.$$

Bohr only considered circular orbits so $r$ is constant as well as $v$ and of course $m$. Later elliptical orbits were considered by Sommerfeld and it was proposed, that the integral of $L$ over one period must be an integral multiple of the Planck constant:

$$\oint L d\phi = nh.$$

Now apparently $L$ is independent of $\phi$ and integration yields:

$L 2\pi = nh \Rightarrow L=n\frac{h}{2\pi}$

Which is the same as before. Now I was wondering how I can show that L is independent of $\phi$ because $r$ and $v$ are arguably functions of $\phi$ in the case of elliptical orbits. The velocity $v$ is given by:

$$v=\omega r(\phi)= \frac{d\phi}{dt}r(\phi).$$

And the radius is given by:

$$r(\phi)=\frac{ab}{\sqrt{a^2sin^2(\phi)+b^2cos^2(\phi)}}.$$

I imagine I would have to solve the following equation by integration and all terms containing $\phi$ would cancel out?

$$Ldt=mr(\phi)^2d\phi$$

I'm not very proficient in physics or math, is my line of thinking right? If so it would be great if someone has a suggestion on where I could find this derivation so I can comprehend how $\phi$ cancels out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $1/r$ potential interaction is, fundamentally, the same as what's in gravitationally orbiting bodies. How do you prove that $L$ is constant for those? (a couple of videos on the topic that might be helpful: a [3Blue1Brown video presenting an argument by Feynman showing why orbits are elliptical](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xdIjYBtnvZU), an [AP Physics level lecture on angular momentum and elliptical orbits](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLdlfWT7UN0).

If nothing else, you can work out 
\begin{align}
    \vec{L} &= \vec{r}\times (m\vec{v}) \\
            &= r v \sin\theta \hat{n},
\end{align}
where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{v}$, and $\hat{n}$ is unimportant (it's perpendicular to the ellipse). The crucial part is that the origin is at one focus of the ellipse, so the relationship between $\phi$ and $\theta$ will be very specific.

Also, you're wrong about the formula for the velocity. That is just the component of the velocity around the origin (we call that the $\hat{\phi}$ direction). The velocity will also have a component inward and outward (the $\hat{r}$ direction) that is given by $\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}\phi}\times \frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}t}$. The total velocity vector is given by 
$$ \vec{v} = \frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}t} \hat{r} + r \frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}t} \hat{\phi},$$
and its magnitude will be
\begin{align}
  v & = \sqrt{\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}t} \right)^2 + \left(r \frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)^2} \\
   & = \sqrt{\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}\phi} \right)^2 + r ^2} \times \frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}t}.
\end{align}
Although, all of that is only useful if you have an expression for $\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}t}$. Better is to use energy conservation to say that
$$ E = \frac{1}{2} \mu v^2 - k_C \frac{q_e q_p}{r}, \tag1$$
where $\mu$ is the reduced mass of the atom.

If you solve (1) for $v$ you'll get an expression for the total $v$ in terms of the total energy and $r$ constants. Then, if you work out $\theta$ in terms of $r$ and $\phi$, everything works out much more nicely than if you worry about time.